# Plotting subsets with different shapes

Tags: r, ggplot2

quick question: I have a dataset, which I seperate into a training and a test subset randomly. Then I do some statistical analysis and wanna plot the results together in the same plot, but using different shapes for the two different subsets.

I'm new to ggplot, so my problem is having to supply ggplot with the complete dataset at the beginning. Since I have seperated the data into two sets by random indexing, I can't find the right selection properties for aes()

```
data=read.csv("...",sep=" ")
data$class = as.factor(data$class - 1)
colnames(data)=c("y","x1","x2")
n = dim(data)[1]
order = sample(n)
test = data[order[1:(n/2)],]
train = data[order[(n/2):n,]
#...
ggplot(train) + geom_point( aes(x =x1, y = x2, color = y)) 
# this should be done for the whole dataset, kinda like this
# ggplot(data) + geom_point(aes(x=x1, y=x2, color=y, shape=(index is in test and not train)))
# which is obviously not valid
```

Thanks for your time,
Niklas

Comment: Can we see some example data? This should be straightforward, but want to see some data to make sure we get it right. If you could, plug this into R: dput(head(df,10)). That will supply us with a reproducible example to work with. You probably want to do that for both test and train dfs.

Comment: It's actually a subset of [this](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Wine)

`structure(list(y = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), x1 = c(15.6, 
11.2, 18.6, 16.8, 21, 15.2, 14.6, 17.6, 14, 16), x2 = c(5.64, 
4.38, 5.68, 7.8, 4.32, 6.75, 5.25, 5.05, 5.2, 7.22)), .Names = c("y", 
"x1", "x2"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", 
"8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")`

Comment: Where is the shape variable? Is the shape variable just a 1/0 in the train set?

Comment: There is no shape variable, this is supposed to be a parameter for ggplot. Shape should be determined by beloning to either test or training set

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have 2 data sets as in your example, this is an other way of doing it

```
library(ggplot2)
data = structure(list(y = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), x1 = c(15.6, 11.2, 18.6, 16.8, 21, 15.2, 14.6, 17.6, 14, 16), x2 = c(5.64, 4.38, 5.68, 7.8, 4.32, 6.75, 5.25, 5.05, 5.2, 7.22)), .Names = c("y", "x1", "x2"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
data = data.frame(data)
n = dim(data)[1]
order = sample(n)
test = data[order[1:(n/2)],]
train = data[order[(n/2):n],]

ggplot(test)+geom_point(aes(y = x1,x=x2))+
  geom_point(data = train, aes(y = x1,x = x2), pch = 10, col = "dargreen")
```

Answer (score 0):

If we assume that the datasets have the same columns:

```
# Loading data    
data <- structure(list(y = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("0", "1"), class = "factor"), x1 = c(15.6, 11.2, 18.6, 16.8, 21, 15.2, 14.6, 17.6, 14, 16), x2 = c(5.64, 4.38, 5.68, 7.8, 4.32, 6.75, 5.25, 5.05, 5.2, 7.22)), .Names = c("y", "x1", "x2"), row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "data.frame")
n = dim(data)[1]
order = sample(n)
test = data[order[1:(n/2)],]
train = data[order[(n/2):n,]

test$identifier <- as.factor(1) # mark the test with 1
train$identifier <- as.factor(0) # mark the train with 0

df_out <- rbind(test,train) # combine the dataframes

ggplot(df_out,aes(x = x1,y = x2,color = y, shape = identifier)) + geom_point() # plot the new df
```

This produces:

[image: Graph with different shapes based on dataset]